# A bad performance of upserting item to a million-document collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

It takes 700~800 ms to `upsert` an item into a collection, which is containing about 2 million documents. I have tried the functions as following,

```
Model.findOneAndUpdate()

bulk.find({...}).upsert().updateOne()
```

But both of them takes about almost 1 second to upsert ONE item.

I have another 1 million items to insert/upsert, so it will takes me several days. How can I improve it?

Comment: Have you used the [explain](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/explain-results/) functionality to analyse your query plan?

Comment: Can we have the schema of the collection please?

Comment: And can we have the `find({...})` arguments? Maybe its about indexes.

Comment: Oh, my god, I had forgot to add index for the `find`ing item.

Comment: @VinceBowdren Can `explain` analyse a `upsert` or `findAndModify` operation?

Answer (score 1):

Adding an Index for the querying item will accelerate the process.